# Redux toolkit using createAsyncThunk and typescript error handling

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux-toolkit

I have re-read the documentation a few times and can't seem to figure out an error I'm receiving.

For some reason I need to define the error type in `getAccounts` and `accountsSlice`, even though in the documentation it says I shouldn't if I pass `rejectValue` type and `return rejectWithValue(error as ServerError)`.

```js
interface ServerError {
  statusCode: number
  description: string
}

export const getAccountsSlice = createAsyncThunk<
  GetAccountsState,
  {
    rejectValue: ServerError
  }
>('accountsSlice/getAccounts', async (_, { rejectWithValue }) => {
    try {
      // handle fulfillment
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('REQUEST ERROR --', error)
      return rejectWithValue(error as ServerError)
    }
  }
)

export const accountsSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'accountsSlice',
  initialState,
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder
      .addCase(getAccountsSlice.pending, (state) => {
         ...
      })
      .addCase(getAccountsSlice.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
         ...
      })
      .addCase(getAccountsSlice.rejected, (state, action) => {
        return {
          ...state,
          // must add as ServerError or I get an error
          error: action.payload as ServerError,
          isLoading: false
        }
      })
  }
})
```

In addition, having `rejectValue` typed in `createAysncThunk` I get this error when trying to `dispatch(getAccounts)`:

```
Expected 1 arguments, but got 0.
```

Answer (score 2):

You should `dispatch(getAccounts())`, not `dispatch(getAccounts)`.

For that you need to type the argument as `void`, and that is also where your error is: Generic arguments are positional - the config object is the third argument and you omitted the second. That way, your `getAccounts` expected an argument in the form `{ rejectValue: ServerError }`.

You need to type it

```
export const getAccountsSlice = createAsyncThunk<
  GetAccountsState,
  void,
  {
    rejectValue: ServerError
  }
>
```